# Help in identifying this weed with toothed leaves, tiny white flowers, found under snow cover - FOUND: ID - Thlaspi arvense

Tags: identification, lawn, wildflowers

I found this weed on my lawn under melting snow cover. It has toothed leaves hugging the stems; tiny white flowers in bunches; older and rounder leaves surrounding the flower bunches:

[image: overview of plant]

[image: closeup of flowers and older leaves]

[image: closeup of toothed leaf]

Does anyone know what it is? 
Thank you!

Comment: It looks like it could be a mustard. Are the flowers four-petalled? Does the plant have a spicy odor if you crush some leaves? A picture with the flowers open would be helpful. I strongly recommend that you not allow this plant to set seed.

Comment: I agree with @Jurp. It is in the family of mustard. Often difficult to identify, but you have the fruits! Could you tell us some more about where you live? I expect Norther hemisphere (because of snow).

Comment: @Jurp Yes there are four petals. I'll check later on this week for the scent, when it'll be less windy and the plant stronger.The second picture is the closer I can get with my camera; the flowers are too small to be picked up if my focus is too close. Haha, you're saying this warning to the wrong person. :)  I'm a forager, so I look for edible wild greens, and allow them to get more "domesticated".

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I live in Québec, Zone 4. :)  I haven't thought of mustard! I thought they flowered much later on in the summer...

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi  I found it: Thlaspi arvense - Field Penny-cress (http://www.habitas.org.uk/flora/species.asp?item=2841) You guys were right, it was in the mustard family, but I had to check the Netherlands varieties, as those grow much earlier in the spring. And very happy to learn they're edibles... tastes quite peppery, a bit like a tame wasabi.

Comment: @Jurp I found it: Thlaspi arvense - Field Penny-cress (http://www.habitas.org.uk/flora/species.asp?item=2841) You guys were right, it was in the mustard family, but I had to check the Netherlands varieties, as those grow much earlier in the spring. And very happy to learn they're edibles... tastes quite peppery, a bit like a tame wasabi.

Comment: The reason I recommended that you pull it before seeding is because its seedpods will likely "shatter" when ripe, throwing seed many feet away from the mother plant. Since you're a forager, this may not be so bad at first, but you CAN have too much of a good thing, right? :) I think that you should also enter your ID as an answer to your own question, so that future users can find it easier.

Comment: @Jurp Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Hint: it’s perfectly ok to answer your own question if you found the answer... thus future readers can also benefit from it.

Comment: @Stephie Thanks! I was trying to find where I could answer, but now I found it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Answered: the Field Penny-Cress, Thlaspi arvense (http://www.habitas.org.uk/flora/species.asp?item=2841). In the mustard family, easily identifiable (once you know that the little round green "leaves" are in fact seed pods); but in the Netherlands varieties, as they grow much earlier in spring.
Bonus: they're edibles, with a tame wasabi-like aftertaste.